# Is there a jQuery plugin that will populate an element with an array of checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

We have several reports that will require the user to select from an array of options, which we will present to them via checkboxes. We want to waterproof this process (by using the DRY principle). We want to be able to do something like this:

CSS:

```
.invisible {
    display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="someOptions" class="invisible"></section>
```

jQuery:

```
//some event
$('someOptions')buildSectionHTML('some caption', someArrayOfCheckBoxVals).removeClass('invisible');
```

...where "buildSectionHTML" would generate appropriately sized and labeled html based on the args. IOW, if passed "Elvin Bishop" and "[{'Travelin Shoes', 'Pigboy Crabshaw', 'Sugar Dumplin', 'Rock My Soul, 'Struttin My Stuff'}]" it would generate HTML like:

```
Elvin Bishop
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
_| Travelin Shoes   _|Pigboy Crabshaw   _|Sugar Dumplin
_|Rock My Soul  _|Struttin My Stuff
```

(the "_|"s represent checkboxes, but they should all align, column-like, not helter skelter like the text above displays).

Is there a jQuery plugin that meets this need, or am I better off just writing my own jQuery function for it, or is there a better avenue to cruise down?

Comment: I am not aware of any pluggin, but it is really simple to do. Try to write a function in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for js it's pretty simple (here's a plugin approach):

```
(function($){
  $.fn.extend({
    appendCheckboxes: function(name,labels){
      var container = this;
      $.each(label, function(i,l){
        var label = $.isObject(labels) ? i : l,
            value = $.isObject(labels) ? l : i;
        $('<label>').append(
          $('<input>',{'type':'checkbox','name':name}).val(value),
          label
        ).appendTo(container);
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Example:

```
//
// in both examples, the first argument is the name of the checkboxes.
// the second argument can vary, as shown below:
//

// populate using an array
// array values are labels, array indexes are values
$('#container1').appendCheckboxes('foo',['Apple','Banana','Cranberry','Dill']);

// Populate using an object
// keys are labels, values are values
$('#container2').appendCheckboxes('bar',{
    'Apple':1,'Banana':2,
    'Cranberry':3,'Dill':4
});
```

As far as alignment, you can easily use CSS for this (as I've done in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kFyq/) that supports this answer).

Comment: Is an Exmaple a Canadian expat?

Comment: It's after 4 english. ;-)

Comment: I'm not seeing in this code where it specifies the number of columns. I forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/kmacV/2/ (AFAIK, that's legal in America) and added a 3rd container with a bunch of stuff, and they are still all stuffed into two columns. Is there a workaround to pass a "number of columns" arg to the function/plugin?

Comment: Oh, I see, it's controlled by the CSS.

Comment: That was great, Brad; I extended your example (http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/kmacV/5/), copied the CSS to a stylesheet in a test site, copied the plugin code to a js file, referenced them, copied the html into a page, put the "regular" jQuery in the script section, and voila! It works like a champ.

Comment: Glad to hear it clay. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Given the specific nature of what you're trying to do, it would be much simpler just to write the code yourself. Something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $('element').append('<input type="checkbox" name="'+somevar+'"/>'.textvar);
});
```

If you wanted to do something fancy with columns, you could easily wrap a `div` around it with a column width class and float properties. (Or if you're looking for something more complex, something like [boostrap's grid system](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)).